# Handling OpenFeint data when offline

Tags: iphone, openfeint

How does one handle OpenFeint requests when the device is offline?

e.g. Posting high scores and unlocking achievements.

What if the player is offline, how is this handled?

Does code need to be added to request the next time the device is online?

Is there built in support for this by openfeint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all handled internally by OpenFeint. When the system is offline, it uses a local data cache, and then syncs with its servers the next time it's online.